# Icon of installed apps with snap don't appear in apps list

Tags: user-interface

When I install an app with snap install command , it's icon does not appear in the apps lost and I have to run it with snap run command .

How can I add it's icon to the apps list???

Comment: which app did you installed?

Comment: to understand you... can you see the entry but no the icon?

Answer (score 1):

1) You may have to reboot. I've installed apps via snap before, like Brave, and they appear in the Applications menu but with a generic icon. The icon is there after rebooting. As Sebastian noted below, logging out/logging in should work too.

2) You can edit the **.desktop** file. It will either be in `/etc/share/applications` or from your home directory it will be in `.local/share/applications`

3) You can install a program from the AppCenter called **AppEditor** and use it to create a menu item. It's essentially a more user friendly way of the instructions in #2.

Comment: In the first case (1) there's no need to reboot just relog (log off/log in)